# BigQuery regexp replace character between quotes

Tags: regex, google-bigquery, regexp-replace

I'm trying to use the [BigQuery function regexp_replace](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_replace) for the following scenario:

Given a string field with comma as a delimiter, I need to only remove the commas within double quotes.

I found the following regex to work in the website but it seems that the BigQuery function doesn't support Lookahead groups. Could you please help me find an equivalent expression that is supported by the Big Query function regexp_replace?

https://regex101.com/r/nxkqtb/3

Big Query example code not supported:

```
WITH tbl AS (
    SELECT 'LINE_NR="1",TXT_FIELD="Some text",CID="0"' as text
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'LINE_NR="2",TXT_FIELD=",,Some text",CID="0"' as text
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'LINE_NR="3",TXT_FIELD="Some text ,",CID="0"' as text
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'LINE_NR="4",TXT_FIELD=",Some ,text,",CID="0"' as text
    )

SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE(text, r'(?m),(?=[^"]*"(?:[^"\r\n]*"[^"]*")*[^"\r\n]*$)', "")
FROM tbl;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach (assuming you know in advance keys within the text field)

```
select text,
  ( select string_agg(replace(kv, ',', ''), ',' order by offset)
    from unnest(regexp_extract_all(text, r'((?:LINE_NR|TXT_FIELD|CID)=".*?")')) kv with offset
  ) corrected_text
from tbl;
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]